# make part of line copyable in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to make part of line copyable  (like links) in VSCode?
for example this is a line in my file :

```
MONGO_URI = mongodb+srv://something
```

I want to make "mongodb+srv://something" copyable so that when I click on it, it will be copied (so lazy :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) and the `"surround"` property of the `selectby.regex` command

If you want to be able to select this select range when you use the command from the Command Palette you have to name it in a `settings.json`

```json
  "selectby.regexes": {
    "mongodb-srv": {
      "surround": "mongodb\\+srv:.*",
      "copyToClipboard": true
    }
  }
```

And use this name in the key binding

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+m",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": ["mongodb-srv"]
  }
```

In v1.3.0 you can also define the search range in the key binding:

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+m",  // or any other key combo
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "selectby.regex",
    "args": { "surround": "mongodb\\+srv:.*", "copyToClipboard": true }
  }
```

Place the cursor somewhere inside the string and use the key binding.

Comment: I should put this code in settings.json ?

Comment: @SMarziSM `keybindings.json`

Comment: I installed selcet by and add this command to keybindings.json but it dosen't work :(

Comment: @SMarziSM Oops, I did not try it first. I have changed the extension to support this, use v1.3.0